# Simple SELECT query is slow with ~4Gb table (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table called `tablename` with the following structure:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tablename_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tablename_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11271577 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The current size of this table is `4.1Gb` currently and I expect it to get larger.

I'm running a fairly simple SQL `SELECT` query which looks like:

```sql
SELECT `type`, `data`, `created_at`
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `type` = 'PURCHASE'
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Essentially, we're looking to return only ***one*** (and no more) of the most recent rows in this DB (of type `PURCHASE`). Most data in this table is not of type `PURCHASE`.

On a production database with 4gb of RAM, this query can be seen to take as long as 1 minute and 1 second (which seems way too long).

```sql
SELECT `type`, `data`, `created_at`
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `type` = 'PURCHASE'
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
LIMIT 1;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 00:01:01.8 */
```

On other runs (same box, same server), I've seen it take between `27 seconds` and `36.48` seconds.

I'd like to see this down to a couple seconds at most if possible.

The version of MariaDB is 10.3.27 (running on *nix virtual cloud instance with 4Gb RAM and "*General Purpose (SSD) volumes*"). Is this normal? What can be done to speed up this query? Would the bottleneck be mostly associated with RAM or disk speed or something else?

It may be worth noting that a lot of new records are being written/inserted into this same table at the same time this `SELECT` statement is likely to be executing, so this could be slowing things down (waiting for `INSERT` statements to finish perhaps).

Comment: Imagine you are the DB engine. You are given such a query and have an unordered table (think Excel spreadsheet) in front of you. How would you search through it for the latest date? You have to go through the whole table. Now imagine you have instead a dictionary-style index, sorted first by `type`, then by `created_date`, and you have a lookup reference for where each row is. Now it's simple, go to `PURCHASE` take the first date instantly.

Comment: Good explanation and makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT `type`, `data`, `created_at`
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `type` = 'PURCHASE'
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You want an index on `tablename(type, created_at desc)`.

Comment: Thanks. I applied `alter table tablename add index \`tablename_type_created_at desc_index\`(\`type\`, \`created_at\`)` which took about 3 minutes to run. The former SELECT statement now runs in about half a second as expected (much better!)

Comment: The `desc` part is not needed since indexes can be walked backwards.

Comment: MariaDB actually gave an error when I tried to run `alter table tablename` with `desc` on the end of `created_at`. Fine without.

Comment: "Half a second"?  I would expect only a few milliseconds.  Still, I agree with the index (with or without the `DESC`.)  Check the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`; I would use about 1500M.

Comment: https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl 1.7.21 seems to recommend `>= 4.5G` for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Why such a large difference?

Comment: @JamesSpittal - The buffer_pool should be significantly smaller than the RAM.  Since the server has 4GB of RAM, setting the buffer_pool to 4.5G would lead to a lot of swapping, which is _very_ bad for performance.